# fviz_cluster() in R does show text although geom="point"?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

`scatterplot_clust <- fviz_cluster(object=list(data = df, cluster = otu,geom = "point",repel=T,show.clust.cent=T,main="clusters of df",color=rainbow))`

When I compute this R code it shows me a scatterplot but with text (although a specified `geom="point"` ), furthermore the title is not showing. There is no error message. What is wrong here? Why isn´t R doing what the code says. I used the package `factoextra` .

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation, it says you don't need to wrap the arguments of `fviz_cluster()` in a list when using `hclust()`.

This example works so I suggest you to remove `list()` in argument definitions and instead using `hcut()` which performs both the clustering and the cut.

```r
library(factoextra)

data("iris")
head(iris)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -5])
hc.cut <- hcut(iris.scaled, k = 3, hc_method = "complete")
fviz_cluster(hc.cut, geom = "point", ellipse.type = "norm"  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I do not have a kmeans object, that is why I used the list.

Comment: `fviz_cluster()` accepts different objects. Are you saying you have an object not included in the standard ones? If so, what is the cluster object you are using?

Comment: I would like to use an ```hclust()``` object, but that is not working. data and cluster are data.frames

Comment: Please, see the edit post which now reflects the usage with `hclust` object.

Comment: ```Can't handle an object of class hclust``` that is the error I am getting. I cant use ```hcut()``` because I want to cut the dendrogram at a specific height (and not k), that is why I am using ```hclust``` (and then later ```cutree```). But thank you ;)

Comment: Then I suggest to raise an issue on Github [here](https://github.com/kassambara/factoextra).

Answer (score 0):

you can try it again like this:

```
fviz_cluster(object=list(data = df, cluster = otu),geom = "point",repel=T,show.clust.cent=T,main="clusters of df",color=rainbow)
```

please concentrate on the")" you placed.